# How can I map two buttons to scroll emulation?

Tags: x11, xorg, libinput

I have a Logitech Trackman Marble, which has 2 large buttons and two tiny ones. It also has no scroll wheel.

Using [this configuration from the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse#Using_libinput), it is possible to configure one of the small buttons as the scroll modifier.

However, I also use the mouse in left-handed mode, and the other small button is impossible to press. So I want **both** of the small buttons to enable scrolling.

I tried to add the following button mapping, to map button 9 to button 8 so they both trigger scrolling. But the second button just triggers the back button.

```
Option          "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8"
```

How can I do this?

Or alternatively, how can I easily switch between a right-handed and left-handed configuration? If I could configure the fourth useless button to "mirror" the mouse, that'd be super nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trackball, and this is my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-logievdev.conf` for enabling scrolling:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Logitech USB Trackball"
    MatchProduct    "Logitech USB Trackball"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    Driver          "libinput"
    Option          "ButtonMapping"         "1 0 3 4 5 0 0 8 2"
    Option          "ScrollMethod"          "button"
    Option          "ScrollButton"          "8"
EndSection
```

Note that you only need the `Option "ScrollMethod"` and `Option "ScrollButton"` lines to enable trackball scrolling.

Perhaps my hand is just different enough from yours, but I find all four buttons to be usable for me. That's why I've assigned the harder-to-reach small button to middle mouse button (button 2), for those rare old X11 programs that occasionally need it. That's also why I don't use the `Option "MiddleEmulation"` that was used in the Arch Wiki configuration you linked.

It might be that the `ScrollButton` option is handled before `ButtonMapping`, allowing you to assign the scrolling to one and only one button.

To switch between configurations, you could use something like this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
MOUSENAME="Logitech USB Trackball"
CUR_SC_BUTTON=$(xinput --list-props "$MOUSENAME" | grep "Scrolling Button (" | cut -d : -f 2)
case $CUR_SC_BUTTON in
    8)
        # mouse is currently right-handed, switch to left
        xinput --set-prop "$MOUSENAME" "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 9
        xinput --set-button-map "$MOUSENAME" 3 2 1 4 5 6 7 9 8
        # note: may need to switch 9 and 8 around, depending on how
        # ButtonMapping and ScrollingButton interact
        ;;
    9)
        # mouse is currently left-handed, switch to right
        xinput --set-prop "$MOUSENAME" "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 8
        xinput --set-button-map "$MOUSENAME" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        ;;
esac
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this script myself, I just now wrote it.

To have the "useless" button switch mouse configurations, you would use the appropriate tool in your desktop environment of choice to assign this script to run when that mouse button is pressed.